# Examples of when to use ではありません、ではない、じゃありません、 じゃない

Tags: word-choice, nuances

I'm looking for example situations of when to use each level of politeness. I know they all are the same but when situational wise to use each one is where I am having confusion.

Comment: And ではない, if you want to have all combinations of [±formal] and [±polite].

Answer (score 2):

In terms of situational usage, it partially depends on how one wishes to present themselves.

That said, the way I've used these forms is as follows:

> ではありません

- Formal writing, such as a report or documentation

> ではない

- Formal writings in combination with `ので` when giving an explanation.
- Formal writings with longer sentences in place of `ではありません` (both between phrases and at the end of the compound sentence).

> じゃありません

- Formal conversation, such as during an interview.

> じゃない

- Casual conversation with friends and / or casual writing such as text messages

Comment: I believe that for scientific writing (which is also formal), such as for reports or documentation, ではない is standard and ではありません would usually be considered too wordy.

Comment: In that context, is it used in the middle of a sentence still (to combine two clauses), or would the sentence end with ではない?

Comment: Both in the middle in the sentence, like you also mention, *and* at the end of a sentence.